# Is it possible to have different types of nodes in a neo4j graph database

Tags: java, database, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

for example, if I have two nodes created in a transaction

```
node1 = db.graphDb.createNode();
node2 = db.graphDb.createNode();

// index user id
node1.setProperty("abc", "fkdjasflasdjlf");
db.nodeIndex.add(node1, "abc", "fkdjasflasdjlf");
```

node1 has property "abc" but node2 doesn't.

Then I tried to query on nodes, like list all the nodes that have property "abc" equals "fkdjasflasdjlf".

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(*) WHERE n.abc = 'fkdjasflasdjlf' return n ");
```

Neo4j generates exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: The property 'abc' does not exist on Node[0]
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:35)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:29)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.Equals.isMatch(ComparablePredicate.scala:60)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:29)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.FilterPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(FilterPipe.scala:29)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:390)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:138)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:562)
at neo4j.TestNodeSearch.main(TestNodeSearch.java:59)
    Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: 'abc' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
at       
    org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:179)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:52)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:155)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Property.apply(Property.scala:33)
```

So is there any way to support "different types" of nodes or currently, only one type of node is supported?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `HAS` function.

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.abc) AND n.abc = 'fkdjasflasdjlf' return n ");
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you need to verify that the `abc` property exists on the node before evaluating its value, or else an exception is thrown. There are two ways to do this:

1. Using the `has` [function](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-property-exists):

   `START n=node(*) WHERE has(m.abc) AND n.abc = 'fkdjasflasdjlf' return n`
2. Using the `!` [property operator](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-default-false-if-property-is-missing) (which evaluates to false for missing properties).

   `START n=node(*) WHERE n.abc! = 'fkdjasflasdjlf' return n`

As a general note, nodes in Neo4j are typeless/schemaless. A node either does or does not have a property you're looking for, you just need to appropriately handle each case. You can try to enforce a sort of schema by, for example, giving each node a `Type` property, but Neo4j will not enforce any sort of rules for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "has" keyword, such as

```
START m=node(*) WHERE has(m.name) AND m.name ='Micha' RETURN id(m), m.name;
```

As far as node types go, you just need to add a property to each node of type.  The node is just a blank object, by typing them you can differentiate them and link various types together.

A good schema design we have used is a root node which has `Subreference` relationships to `Type = 'Subreference'`.  Then we create nodes of `Type = 'Person'` which are connected to the Subreference nodes by an 'Instance' relationship.  That way to any node there is always a roadmap where you only have to filter on a fraction of the nodes in your database.